# How to Use Dates In For Loop

Tags: for-loop

DateTime LvStartDt = DateTime.Parse(currnrow["HR_LE_START_DATE"].ToString()); //27_01_2019 
    DateTime LvEndDt = DateTime.Parse(currnrow["HR_LE_END_DATE"].ToString());// 04_03_2019 
    DateTime SrcEndDt = DateTime.Parse(dtpToDate.Text);// 31_01_2019

```
if(LvEndDt > SrcEndDt) 
 { 
  for(int j=LvStartDt; j<= LvEndDt; j++)
  { 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: at the top i was declarer date time variable and also commend the data,  easy to understand

Comment: What language are you using and *what is the question*? In any case, modify the question to add extra info, don't post it as comments

Comment: Have you tried something anyway? Do you want to increment by minute, hour, month, year or date? Since `++` is meaningless for dates, have you looked into *which* method actually adds intervals to a date?